# issues centering parts in toc, cannot remove "part"

Tags: table-of-contents

for my thesis I got detailed guidelines from the publisher. So I configured the toc in many ways, getting it almost done. Regarding parts, the latest version looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/uui7oQ9dzw in the toc and like this on the first page of the part: https://www.screencast.com/t/MBI4pOeS9

The last request is to center the parts in the toc, which I could almost resolve, using this:

```
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering\partname~#1~~#2}}}
```

This works almost perfect, but now the addition "Teil" (="Part") appears, and I don't know how to get rid of it: https://www.screencast.com/t/BnJvEWGdLfhM

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[papersize={210mm,297mm},text={113mm,180mm},inner=77mm,outer=20mm,top=34mm,bottom=83mm]{geometry}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill} 
\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontohead}

%formatting the part, chapter,...
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\large}
\addtokomafont{part}{\large}
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\normalsize \bfseries}
\addtokomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\fontsize{11}{11} \bfseries}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{11}{11} \bfseries}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{10}{10} \bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{10}{10} \itshape \mdseries}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{10}{10}\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{font={\bfseries\rmfamily}}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart\autodot}

%formatting entries for part, chapter, ...
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}.}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}\alph{subsubsection})}

%indention
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=1.5em]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=2.5em]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=2.5em,tocnumwidth=1em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=5em,tocnumwidth=1em]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=7.5em,tocnumwidth=1.5em]{subsubsection}

%center toc entry 'part':
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering\partname~#1~~#2}}}

%set the number of the part and the part title in one line (at the first page of the part)
\renewcommand*{\partheadmidvskip}{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart\enskip}
\setkomafont{part}{\usekomafont{partnumber}}

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}



\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
\tableofcontents

\part{my first part}
\chapter{first chapter}
\blindtext
\part{my second part}
\chapter{seconf chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\partname~` from the redefinition of `\addparttocentry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the redefinition of `\addparttocentry` to:

```
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}
  {\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering\protect\ifstr{#1}{}{}{~#1~~}#2}}%
}
```

[image]

Do not load package `titletoc` with a KOMA-Script class.

---

Some additional suggestions:

1. Do not load package `titletoc` with a KOMA-Script class!
2. Remove `\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart\autodot}`. It is overwritten by the later `\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart\enskip}`.
3. Remove `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=1.5em]{part}` and `\addtokomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}`. Add

   `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=0pt,tocpagenumberbox=\gobble]{part}`
    `\newcommand*\gobble[1]{}`

to remove the part page number in ToC.

4. Remove `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}` and add the following to the preamble:

   `\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhalt}`
5. AFAIK package `times` should be replaced by packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot! and thank you very much for the additional information about other packages and workarounds, this is highly appreciated.